# Hide text before seaborn barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I am trying to print a barplot using seaborn

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
g = sns.barplot(x = 'A', y = 'B', data = df)
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

However, before the actual plot, there are two cell which get printed with text something like this

```
out[3]: <Figure size 1152x432 with 0 Axes>
out[3]: [Text(0, 0, 'valueA'),
         Text(0, 0, 'valueB'),
         ....
         Text(0, 0, 'valueZ')]

        <Actual BarPlot>
```

How can I suppress the text before the Actual BarPlot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The setting of text is returning the text objs. Thus; if you take them in a  variable, then no output would be there.

```
var = g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

Answer (score 10):

`set_ticklabels` returns the tick values.  You can either suppress it with a semicolon

```
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90);
```

Or assign the return to a name

```
ticks = g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
```